# How to map Caps Lock key to something useful?

Tags: keyboard

I'm used to mapping Caps Lock to Escape, particularly for use in Vim.

In Ubuntu, this is simple from the GUI. In other distros, a utility like `xmodmap` can be used. I tried this, but it seems that `xmodmap` cannot be installed by `apt`.

Can this sort of remapping be easily accomplished on the RPi?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

On Raspbian, edit the file `/etc/default/keyboard` and then run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`. You may have to restart your terminal and/or the Pi for everything to take effect.

The particulars of what you need to enter depend on what you want to do. For me, this:

```
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT="altgr-intl"
XKBOPTIONS="terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,ctrl:nocaps"
```

makes sure I have US international keyboard layout and <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> acts as <kbd>Control</kbd> (that's the `ctrl:nocaps` part).

Find out more via `man keyboard`.

Comment: In order to figure out that I wanted `caps:escape` as my `XKBOPTIONS` I needed to search through the many options in `/usr/share/doc/keyboard-configuration/xorg.lst`.

Comment: @EricWilson Yea, the documentation is ... suboptimal.

Comment: On Raspbian jessie, at least, this only affects the text console, not the GUI. See [this other answer](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45075/60022) for a solution that affects the GUI.

Comment: For me, only this answer worked, and not the one from @LuísOliveira

Comment: @Bogatyr it depends on which terminal you are using. If you are working without X11 (graphical environment) this is the solution, if you are working on X11 the working solution is in the yzsh reply.
They are  two distinct environment so every one has his own configuration.

Maybe the two answer should be put togheter explaining the context.

Comment: This works fine for me in X11 too on Raspbian buster.

Answer (score 9):

In my case, Raspbian (jessie):

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
...

$ sudo vi ~/.config/lxkeymap.cfg
option = ctrl:swapcaps
```

or

```
option = <something>,ctrl:swapcaps
```

then

```
$ sudo reboot
```

`ctrl:swapcaps` swaps the Ctrl and CapsLock keys. If you'd like to just replace CapsLock and keep the original Ctrl as is, use `ctrl:nocaps` instead.

Comment: Thanks!  This one work for me on jessie.  Editing esc/default/keyboard did not.  Your example swaps ctrl and caps.  To answer the question directly, to map caps to esc use the 'option = caps:escape".

Comment: That last tip should read `ctrl:nocaps` rather than `ctrl:nocap`. Other than that, it worked for me, thanks!

Comment: Didn't work for me, but the accepted answer did.

Answer (score 3):

tl;dr: it can be added through the GUI, in the Keyboard Layout Handler applet's settings.

### Add the Keyboard Layout Handler applet to your panel:

Right click on panel > Panel Settings > Panel Applets tab > Click Add > Scroll and select Keyboard Layout Handler and click Add.

[image]

### Open Keyboard Layout Handler applet's settings:

Right click on the newly added applet > Keyboard Layout Handler Settings.

[image]

### Set xkbmap options

Then on the right find Advanced setxkbmap Options, and input `caps:escape` (or `ctrl:nocaps`, etc, [here's a list](https://gist.github.com/jatcwang/ae3b7019f219b8cdc6798329108c9aee)). Multiple options probably need to be comma separated.

[image]

There's a green icon on the right of the box, I suppose one should click on it to save the settings, though there's no feedback to confirm. I can't remember if I needed to reboot for the changed to take effect.

Answer (score 2):

`xmodmap` can indeed be installed on the RPi using `apt`:

```
apt-get install x11-xserver-utils
```

To make your <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key act as <kbd>Esc</kbd>, you could then run

```
xmodmap -e 'clear Lock' -e 'keycode 0x42 = Escape'
```