# How to remap Caps Lock to ESC

Tags: keyboard

**UPDATE:** The method below seems to work fine if the Pi boots into commandline, but doesn't work if Pi is configured to boot into X.

====

I've just started dabbling with the Raspberry Pi. Being a frequent Vim user, as well as having bash/zsh in permanent vi mode. I'm wondering how I could map the Caps Lock key to ESC.

On my Macbook, I use [Seil](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/seil.html).

With the Pi, I've been modifying the `/etc/default/keyboard` file to achieve the same effect (and calling `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` after each config change).  Unfortunately, it hasn't worked.

My `keyboard` file looks like this:

```
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS="caps:swapescape"

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Has anyone successfully done this?

Comment: [Related, older question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5333/how-to-map-caps-lock-key-to-something-useful/5335).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after booting into X you can use `xmodmap` to remap any key of your keyboard:

just use the command `xmodmap -e 'keycode <value>=<action>'`
and with `xev` you can get every keycode (and also the used [action/keysym](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/List_of_Keysyms_Recognised_by_Xmodmap))

---

in your case it would probably be `xmodmap -e 'keycode 66=Escape'`.

by the way: if you don't want to type the command every time you login manually, you can insert the line into your *.bash_profile* and it is executed automatically with your login.

---

or if you want to remap more than one key you can create a file e.g. *~/.remap* and insert something like this:

> keycode   8 =
>   
> keycode   9 = Escape
>   
> keycode  10 = 1 plus plusminus infinity
>   
> keycode  11 = 2 quotedbl leftdoublequotemark rightdoublequotemark
>   
> keycode  12 = 3 asterisk numbersign leftcaret
>   
> keycode  13 = 4 ccedilla Ccedilla slash
>   
> keycode  14 = 5 percent bracketleft
>   
> keycode  15 = 6 ampersand bracketright
>   
> keycode  16 = 7 slash bar backslash
>   
> keycode  17 = 8 parenleft braceleft Ograve
>   
> keycode  18 = 9 parenright braceright Ocircumflex
>   
> keycode  19 = 0 equal notequal Uacute

in this file the [keysyms (actions)](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/List_of_Keysyms_Recognised_by_Xmodmap) are separated and the = is surrounded by a space!

within XServer you can use up to **4 keysyms triggered** by the following:

1. the action by normally pressing the key once
2. the action when additionally **Shift**-Signal (normally *Shift_L*/*Shift_R*) is pressed
3. the action when additionally **Mode_switch**-Signal (normally *Alt_L*/*Alt_R*) is pressed
4. the action when additionally **Shift** and **Mode_switch** is pressed

for sure you can also remap **Mode_switch** with a line like this:

> `keycode <value> = Mode_switch`

and then execute `xmodmap ~/.remap` in the terminal or add it to *.bash_profile* like the upper "one-key-command".

Comment: Thanks @DJCrashdummy, the command `xmodmap -e 'keycode 66=Escape'` works. Unfortunately, I need to execute this command every time I start Terminal from within X. I boot by default to commandline, and start X from there when I need it. I've tried adding the `xmodmap` line to `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc`.  Any suggestions?

Comment: `xmodmap` only works when X is running! - if that's clear and *.bash_profile* still don't work as expected you can maybe try the global */etc/profile* or */etc/bash.bashrc*...

Comment: It's all good. included `xmodmap` in .bashrc and it works fine now. Even know I boot to commandline, and start X from there. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me.

```
$ touch ~/.xmodmap
$ nano ~/.xmodmap
```

enter the following for ~/.xmodmap

```
clear Lock
keycode 0x42 = Escape
```

trigger the override with following

```
$ xmodmap ~/.xmodmap
```

if you like, you can place it in the end of either ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile

```
if [ -f ~/.xmodmap ]; then
  xmodmap ~/.xmodmap
fi
```