# Some keys not working with Norwegian keyboard

Tags: pi-4, keyboard

I have a raspberry pi model b.
I am using it with a WASD Code V2 keyboard, normally configured for my MacBook, with a Norwegian keyboard layout. The locale/keyboard settings are all set to Norwegian on the PI. I’m not using a GUI.

Most keys work as expected (including Norwegian æøå), but some keys don’t.
shift+4 gives a “*”-like symbol and option does not seem to work at all.
This makes it hard for me to write programs.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Olaven

Comment: Are settings correct in `/etc/default/keyboard`?

Comment: If you can't find another solution, you can manually tweak the keymap *in a GUI context* [with this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap) and on the console with `loadkeys`.

Comment: Thanks. Loadkeys respond with “cannot find defkeymap.map” when passing —default. And “couldn’t get a file descriptor referring to the console” when just running it. How do I use it correctly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to map Caps Lock key to something useful?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5333/how-to-map-caps-lock-key-to-something-useful)